# SQL: Querying a Column Based on Duplicate Values in Another Column

Tags: sql

I am still a noobie at SQL and this one issue is a doozy for me.

I have a table called NAMES that has NAME_ID, ALIAS_ID, and DOD columns (DOD = Date of Death). NAME_ID is the unique ID, whereas ALIAS_ID is populated with the NAME_ID if it is an alias of the NAME.

I need to query and count all alias_id's where the name_id has more than 1 alias associated and DOD is not null.

```
NAME_ID     ALIAS_ID      DOD
4434        0             NULL
4444        0             4/5/2000    
58777       0             2/15/1993
58778       4444          4/5/2000
58779       58777         2/15/1993
58780       4444          4/5/2000
58781       58777         2/15/1993
```

Note that there is a NAME_ID = 4444 that has two alias' with NAME_ID = 58778, 58780. There is also NAME_ID = 58777 that has an alias with NAME_ID = 58779, 58781. DOB for these records are not null. These are the records that I need to query as there can only be one DOD linked to all NAME_ID (the alias_id should not have a DOD). I am looking for a result similiar to:

```
NAME_ID    #OFALIASWITHDOD 
4444       2
58777      2
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then the query you want is:

```
select nn.name_id, count(*) as num_aliases
from names n join
     names nn
     on n.alias_id = nn.name_id
where nn.dod is not null
group by nn.name_id;
```

Comment: The result that I'm getting with your query is still pulling name_id's with DOD = NULL. Thank you for the input.

Comment: The `where` clause should pretty much not allow that.

Comment: I understand - the format that is coming back is correct. It's just like how my last command output looks in my question; however, when I select * from NAMES where name_id = (a result recnum), that name has a DOD = NULL. I know that there are only two name_id's that have alias_id's with a DOD in my database; it's just a matter of getting those two in the results as I will need to run this query on another database as well (where I don't know how many there are). With your query I'm getting back over 2,000 hits.